# Table not removed in EDMX after deleting in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, poco

AM working with MVC4 VS2012 and EF5.

I created a EDMX using the DataBase and the POCO(TT) Classes were generated Automatically.

Followed this way [Entity Framework 5 and Visual Studio 2012 POCO Classes in Different Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375090/entity-framework-5-and-visual-studio-2012-poco-classes-in-different-project) to move POCO to different Project.

Now i edit my datatype (Int to String or AllowNull) or delete my table in SQL Server. i come and update my model(EDMX). But changes are not reflected.

Am i doing wrong or missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are missing anything.

I'm unsure of the logic used by the designer when it decides what to update. From experience it seems to mostly add new. I haven't seen much updating.

I tend to just delete the table and add it again as the least painful route. This will remove any custom mapping, so it's not ideal if your entities are very different from your tables.